# Undefined method *_path when trying to use form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, form-for

## Category controller:

```
  def new
    @cat = Category.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end
```

## View:

```
%p Add new category:
~form_for(@cat) do |f|
  %div.field
    ~f.label :name
    ~f.text_field :name
  %div.field
    ~f.label :description
    ~f.text_area :description
  %div.field
    ~f.submit
```

## Routes:

```
 resources :category
```

When I try to load category/new in the browser I get:

```
undefined method `categories_path' for #<#<Class:0x10d9c9ee8>:0x10d9b0768>
Extracted source (around line #3):
1: %h1 Category#new
2: %p Add new category:
3: ~form_for(@cat) do |f|
4:   %div.field
5:     ~f.label :name
```

Any ideas why my form isn't showing?
Also, on my category/index page, where I want to show all categories, under the list of categories I'm getting `#<Category:0x10d736b40>`. Can I get rid of that somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit long for a comment so I've added the following as an answer instead.

If you want a singular resource you need to do:

```
resource :category
```

Which will [generate only 6 routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources) (no index):

```
GET     /category/new   new
POST    /category       create
GET     /category       show
GET     /category/edit  edit
PUT     /category       update
DELETE  /category       destroy
```

But your controller will still be plural, unless you do the following:

```
resource :category, controller: :category
```

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how I can get rid of the `#<Category:0x10d736b40>` string?

Comment: I'm not familiar with haml, but you might be adding the equivalent of a `=` when you're iterating over them. For example `<%= @categories.each do |cat| %>` instead of `<% @categories.each do |cat| %>`. Although that might return an array, can't remember off the top of my head.

Comment: You're right, I was using a `~` instead of a `-` before my each do statement. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The route should be

```
resources :categories
```

not

```
resources :category
```

Comment: That's still giving an error (thoug it's a shorter one), `uninitialized constant CategoriesController`

Comment: make sure your categories controller is named `categories_controller.rb`

Comment: That fixed it, thanks. But shouldn't I be able to use singular names for controllers?

Comment: I've added my reply as an answer since it's too long for a comment